# How does internal method get the props in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I am new to react and javascript. I have been learning react and react router and a tutorial i was following was using withRouter. Anyway, I found some code how to reimplement withRouter as it is no longer supported. My question is the following. How does the internal function get the props argument. Where does it come from? Thank you all in advance for the response, I have been stuck on this for a while.

```
function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }
```

And this is the whole snippet of the Component code:

```
import { Routes, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
  
function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }
  
  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes
  }
}

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>home page component</div>
  );
}

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>main component {this.props.dishes}</div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' element={<HomePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MainPage));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, BTW. Just FYI in case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] just yet, there are 100% completely optional steps you can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) to help curate content on the site. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking how Higher Order Components (HOCs) work. HOCs are *just* special Higher Order Functions. In other words, they are functions that *return* another function.

Take the basic HOC example:

```
const withExample => Component => props => {
  ... maybe some logic ...
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

`withExample` is called and passed a React component as an argument:

```
const MyExample = withExample(BaseExample);
```

This returns a function, i.e. a React component with this definition:

```
const MyExample = props => {
  ... maybe some logic ...
  return <BaseExample {...props} {...additionalProps} />;
};
```

This is just a regular React function component, the `props` come just like they do for any other React component.

```
<MyExample prop1="prop1" prop2={23} />
```

In your code example both `withRouter` and `connect` are HOCs, each taking a React component, augmenting/injecting additional props, and returns the decorated component.

Comment: This is a great answer! Makes a lot of sense.